# Is it unprofessional to ask the recruiter to pick the time, instead of providing options?

Tags: professionalism, recruitment, scheduling

A recruiter reached out to me for an interview; she asked me to provide her with a few time options that work for me on (...day). She would then go back to her calendar to confirm.

My reply was as follows.

> (...day) works for me. Please let me know what time works best for you
>   and I'll arrange my daily schedule accordingly.

I genuinely wanted to accommodate her schedule. I'll be free on that day and any time slot she will propose, I'll be fine with.

Would that be perceived as normal, or frustrating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With respect I think you are worrying about nothing. It seems like you were polite and also gracious and flexible enough to say you would be available at any time that day for an interview.

I hope your kindness pays off with a great job offer. Best of luck. T

Answer (score 4):

We can't answer this because we are not this person. We don't know if she is frustrated, elated, miffed, lugubrious, etc.

The general rule of thumb is that "the recruiter is working for you" so you should call the shots for the most part when it comes to scheduling instead of putting it back on the recruiter. She is going to make money off you, so she will make herself available. The more you deal with recruiters, the more you will be asked for times when you are available for certain things.

> "The client loves your resume and would like to speak with you! Can
>   you send me some times that you are available and I will send them
>   over to them?"
>
> "The client had a GREAT time talking to you and wants to bring you
>   onsite! Can you please send me some 2 hour blocks next week when you
>   would be available to go see them?"

If you are free all day, then pose a few timeframes on that day.

> "I am available on Monday from 8:30am CST to 11:30am CST and then
>   again from 1pm to 4pm CST. Any time in there works for me for a
>   meeting/phone call."

Answer (score 2):

Because I've been looking for jobs as my schooling ends, I've had a lot of time during my days and sometime entire free days.

In my case if the recruiter says:

> What times are you available Thursday?

I respond with:

> I am available all day. Choose whatever time is most convinient for you. Thank you.

It relays to them that their schedule is busier than yours and that you'd like to provide them with an opportunity to choose what's best for them.

Comment: If you're free all day and that's unlikely to change, then this is perfect. If your own schedule may change, then I'd tweak it a little to something like:   

"I am currently free all day - let me know what time is best for you and I'll block the time off."

Answer (score -1):

But by not providing a scheduled time, they could call you while you’re grocery shopping or at the mechanic or in an area with poor cel service. I’d give a few options or a time slot (4 hour window).

I’m a morning person so if I was given the opportunity, I’d schedule it between 9am to 1pm.

If she responds saying their morning is booked, then I’d say “please allow me an hour to reschedule something” and then I’d email/call back in 45 min confirming the afternoon appointment.

The reason for pretending to reschedule is to show you’re organized and professional.